autohotkey v2 window maximize/minimize toggle hotkey failing
Why is this code randomly failing? It will work consistently and then freezup(either with the window maximized or minimized) at some seemingly random time, requiring me to select 'any window' in order for it to start working again.
It should toggle maximize/minimize the web browser (provided it is open) via lCtrl+tilde. I'll get the same issue randomly trying to toggle notepad via lctrl+1.
<^`::{
    if not WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe"){
        WinActivate("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    }
    else {
        WinMinimize("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    }
}

Don't link v1 code.
I tried writing it out explicitly but no difference i.e. 'if not winactive then else if winactive then else'

WinActive() as the name suggest checks if the window is active which is usually mixed up with WinExist() which checks if the window or the process exists. Another thing is this is not a toggle script. It only checks if the win is active or not. So here's the solution:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

CHROME_HANDLE := "ahk_exe chrome.exe"
Toggle := WinActive(CHROME_HANDLE)

<^`::{
    if(not WinExist(CHROME_HANDLE)){ ;Check if chrome is still alive
        return
    }

    global Toggle
    if(!Toggle){
        WinRestore(CHROME_HANDLE) ;Restores the last size
        Toggle := true
    }else{
        WinMinimize(CHROME_HANDLE)
        Toggle := false
    }
}

